# How to create non-numeric constraints in Mozart/Oz?

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming, oz, mozart

I want to implement a CSP with the variables' domain being non-numeric (something like [lisa ann mary joanna] ). Is there a way to achieve this in Mozart/Oz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to implement such a thing as a language extension in C++, but within the language itself, it is not possible.

The only built-in types of constraints are finite domain constraints (non-negative integers), finite set constraints (constraints on the domain of sets of non-negative ints) and record constraints.

Maybe you can use integer constants to model your problem, e.g.

```
declare
  %% 4 constants
  Lisa = 1
  Ann = 2
  Mary = 3
  Joanna = 4

  %% N will be the constrained variable
  N
in
  N::[Lisa Ann Mary Joanna]
  {Show N}   %% displays N{1#4}, i.e. N is between 1 and 4

  N \=: Mary %% tell: N is not Mary
  {Show N}   %% displays N{1 2 4}, i.e. N is one of 1,2,4
```

If you don't want to work with finite domains, there is the more general idea of logic programming. You can create choice points for different possible values of a variable, e.g.:

```
declare

  proc {Script A}
     A =
     choice
        lisa
     [] ann
     [] mary
     [] joanna
     end
  end

  {Show {SearchOne Script}}  %% displays "[lisa]"
  {Show {SearchAll Script}}  %% displays "[lisa ann mary joanna]"
```

It is also possible to do that with a not statically known number of values, using [Combinators](http://www.mozart-oz.org/documentation/system/node44.html#chapter.combinator).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very informative and helpful. I want to stick to the constraint programming paradigm, in order to take advantage of the propagators as well as be able to mix general constraints with first order logic rules. I think I'm going to use Dictionaries in order to use my constants as integer values in my csp.